# Find all possible combinations to a sum in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to find all possible combination of sums that equal a certain matrix. Let's say I have:

```
a = [1 0 0; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1];
b = [5 0 0; 0 5 0 ; 0 0 5];
```

I start out with matrix `a` and want to produce matrix `b` by using matrix additions of `r1` and `r2`, *e.g*:

```
r1 = [1 0 0; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1];
r2 = [2 0 0; 0 2 0 ; 0 0 2];
```

I would want it to display the matrix, the addition, and the resulting matrix for all combination, I mean: 4r1 (1+1+1+1+1), 1r1+1r2+1r1 (1+1+2+1), 1r2+1r1+1r1 (1+2+1+1), and 2r2 (1+2+2).

This is what I got so far but I can't get it to go through all the combinations:

```
function v = test_r2(a, b)
    if isequal(a,b)==1
        v = [];
        disp('same')
        return
    end
        v= test_r3(a,b);
    end 

function v = test_r3(a, b)`
    r1 = [1 0 0; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1];
    r2 = [2 0 0; 0 2 0 ; 0 0 2];

    r=[{r1} {r2}];

    if isequal(a,b)==1
        v = b;
    else % recursive call

        for k = 1:numel(r)
        for i = nchoosek(1:numel(r),k)'
            r_matrix = r{1,i};
            if(isequal(a + r_matrix,b) ==1)
                disp([a(:)', r_matrix(:)'])
            end      
        end    
    end
```

Basically I want it to go through the cell array and find all possible combinations of those additions that will allow me to get from matrix `a` to matrix `b`. Any help?

Comment: Assuming you have `n` vectors that are needed at most a factor `k` and `k*n!` is not really a big number (upto k=5 and n=10 for example or k =1000 and n=7) you could just make a few nested for loops and store the result in a huge matrix.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all matrices are multiples of the unit matrix?

Comment: DennisJaheruddin - If possible I would like it to not store all the results in a huge matrix. I would like for the matrix sizes (a and b) to be able to expand much larger than the current 3x3 currently

Eitan T - No, it is possible for matrices to be different. For example, r1 could be [0 1 3; 2 1 0; 0 0 1]

Comment: any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're looking to solve the following system for x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub>:

> x<sub>1</sub>∙**r**<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>∙**r**<sub>2</sub> = **b** - **a**

In MATLAB you can do this by following [these instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html) from the official documentation:

```
y = reshape(b - a, [], 1);
R = [r1(:), r2(:)];
x0 = R \ y;                     %// Basic solution
Z = null(R, 'r');               %// Null space of R
```

Any solution of the form: `x = x0 + Z * p` (for any arbitrary vector `p`) should satisfy: `y = R * x`. Note that this might give you tiny errors because of floating point operations, so consider setting a tolerance threshold and rounding them:

```
idx = (x0 - round(x0) < 100 * eps);
x0(idx) = round(x0(idx));
```

Now let's find all possible positive integer combinations of the form `x0 + Z * p`:

```
if isempty(Z)                   %// Only one solution exists
    X = x0;
else
    N = max([ceil(x0); Z(:)]);  %// Set a search range
    U = cell(size(Z, 2), 1);
    [U{:}] = ndgrid(-N:N);
    U = cellfun(@(x)x(:), U, 'UniformOutput', false);
    P = [U{:}];                 %// All possible values for p within search range
    X = bsxfun(@plus, x0(:).', P * Z.');
    X = unique(X(all(X >= 0, 2), :), 'rows');
end

%// Keep only the positive combinations
X = unique(X(all(X >= 0, 2), :), 'rows');
```

#### Example

Let's set the initial conditions first:

```
a = eye(3);
b = 5 * eye(3);
r1 = eye(3);
r2 = 2 * eye(3);
```

After running the first part of the code, we should get:

```
x0 =
     0
     2

Z =
    -2
     1
```

The second part of the code should produce all possible positive integer combinations:

```
X =
     0     2
     2     1
     4     0
```

which correspond to the sums: 0**r**<sub>1</sub> + 2**r**<sub>2</sub>, 2**r**<sub>1</sub> + 1**r**<sub>2</sub> and 4**r**<sub>1</sub> + 0**r**<sub>2</sub>, respectively.